# SQL query - limit and top

Tags: sql

I am writing a SQL command to try and get the average duration of a transaction for the last 30

```
SELECT SUM (end_time - start_time) as sum, 30 as count 
FROM orders 
WHERE customer_id = ".$customer_id." AND status = 'end'
```

How can I edit the sum part at the start so I only get the first 30 to average, as currently its taking the sum of every row

cheers

Jack

Comment: (1) "last 30" doesn't really mean anything.  (2) Sample data and desired results would help.  (3) A database tag is important.

Comment: is the start time and end time a datetime field or? What you are doing at the tail l end there is just giving the number 30 a column name. If you could also clarify what you mean by the last 30? Do you mean in the last 30 minutes or the last 30 transactions? If so do you have an ID value to go off of or is end time the where you wish to order?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 0):

You could select from a subquery that only retrieves the 30 youngest orders (by `start_time`).

The syntax may vary depending on your DBMS.

E.g.

```
SELECT sum(end_time - start_time),
       30 count
       FROM (SELECT start_time,
                    end_time
                    FROM orders
                    ORDER BY start_time DESC
                    LIMIT 30) x;
```

or

```
SELECT sum(end_time - start_time),
       30 count
       FROM (SELECT TOP 30
                    start_time,
                    end_time
                    FROM orders
                    ORDER BY start_time DESC) x;
```

or maybe others.

Maybe this helps to point you in the right direction.